# Failing to install opencv4nodejs on Mac (Apple M1) throws path not found error

Tags: node.js, macos, opencv, npm, apple-m1

INBASDLP13987:~ kanopi$ sudo npm install -g opencv4nodejs
Password:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./install/install.js
npm ERR! info install using lib dir: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR! /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37
npm ERR!   throw new Error('library dir does not exist: ' + libDir)
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: library dir does not exist: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR!     at Object. (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37:9)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kanopi/.npm/_logs/2021-03-25T01_15_39_828Z-debug.log

Please help in resolving this issue...

Also tried the below:

npm i opencv4nodejs
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.4.0: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./install/install.js
npm ERR! info install using lib dir: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR! /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37
npm ERR!   throw new Error('library dir does not exist: ' + libDir)
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: library dir does not exist: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR!     at Object. (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37:9)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kanopi/.npm/_logs/2021-03-25T14_06_03_819Z-debug.log

Comment: also tried "npm I opencv4nodejs"

Answer (score 4):

It worked when specifically installing `opencv-build` before-hand, but make sure neither `opencv-build` nor `opencv4nodejs` are actually defined in package.json dependencies,

So what I did is install them via `postinstall` as such:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm i opencv-build && npm i opencv4nodejs",
```

For this, I first had to install `cmake` in my case.

`brew install cmake`

BTW: It also took quite a while to install `opencv-build` - minutes of very intensive processing - according to the extra heat and sound emitted, and I thought it was stuck at first.

With this approach we can use `opencv4nodejs` but it's not listed as a dependency.

Comment: I did this, but running appium doctor shows it's still not installed. Ran it again and got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late for the original poster, but since I had to search a lot to find a solution, I want to share what helped me with others:

I had to run the following commands to get this fixed:

```
Brew install cmake 
npm i -g node-gyp 
npm i opencv-build 
npm i @u4/opencv4nodejs
```

you may need to run the following command if the link is not automatically created.

```
brew link --force opencv@4
```